# change function parameter to accept children when recursing with const assertion

Tags: typescript

I have an array that looks like:

```
const routes = [
  {
    id: 'root',
    path: '/',
    children: [
      {
        id: 'auth',
        path: 'auth',
        children: [
          {
            id: 'login',
            path: 'login',
          },
          {
            id: 'register',
            path: 'register',
          },
          {
            id: 'resetPassword',
            path: 'reset-password',
          },
          {
            id: 'resendConfirmation',
            path: 'resend-confirmation',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'playground',
        path: 'playground',
        children: [
          {
            id: 'formControlsPlayground',
            path: 'form-controls',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
] as const; // cannot remove this assertion as some other code is dependent on it
```

Please note that I cannot remove the const assertion on above array as some other code is dependent on it.

Now, I store the type of routes array in a new type:

```
type Routes = typeof routes;
```

Then I try to inject element key in each route of routes:

```
const injectElement = (routes: Routes) => {
  const injectedRoutes: RouteObject[] = [];
  for (let route of routes) {
    injectedRoutes.push({
      path: route.path,
      element: 'div', // this string will be replaced by JSX from a lookup whose index will be id of any Route
      children: route.children ? injectElement(route.children) : undefined,
    });
  }
  return injectedRoutes;
};
```

The function is returning RouteObject, which looks like:

```
type RouteObject = {
  id?: string;
  path?: string;
  element?: string;
  children?: RouteObject[];
}
```

The problem with `injectElement` function is that I cannot call it with `routes[0].children`. So, I guess, I need a recursive type for the function parameter. But I don't know how to create one. Also, that recursive type should be constant because I need to read id from that type and need to use that id to index a lookup inside function (refer to comment inside function).

Here is the link to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBtAUDGAb3wJgEsATALhgHIEQpaAaEggBwEMoALG2gPQs2MYDzIAbCnBRgaeUqWKLFlfp2Q9hK0l17rN2naPFSZcnCJ3Ljq6nQkgA5mTBHbHbnwfPX74wC%20rB5EVsZqdDIu0Chw-rZ63vQo0ahxwR5BYYo2IRHJEChQAAqcEBAA7iBwFPHGifwyhVAAtFzlVTV1ilkhuR75TbIUAMLgAGZkcAC23GTg3SoNkWjDLaBgkzNzCxm2vcYAunukBznZ5Pa07BKcAJ5OCIhgtSeKy9e3D08vi2KS0lk8guBH6tny42q0zGYCgCAkEGKX0eSF%20b3qXn4kJm63AcJACMWBDOKmOYRJZOJrEOMDKonA0AA3DABAJRJwwGBGPAUNMQAA3FAwXhkdBlQpwKDzMC09AQEDTIWMHixekUIWimDq9jDWSwcDkKC4XBQO46mAAJSQqHQWFNOpA43g1rQjON9qFVuQKAA8gAjABWKGAsCwNkoAH4aNA4K4nG7PLwozAY3GEzAUBJeXrk6mwPGSP8zLJk17UP6gyHsIc3QFjRtoOQwJWoABRLOK2GYGAACieNpoZbQAEpMAA%20UIEBuwVwtlAUIcQQcuivBqDV7vV9PY3tZ2D9pVOg8QUf9Wdr%20eLgB07EQEB4PbBMGWB5vXnRmezsP4FDI-JYLJsiKcpwnGMAVJIEgwH6QoyDcnDAPO0F3DAABSADKAAaMDjAg0y0jAjggAA1og7DgTwICFE26oAB7gZB0EahQMCOrSYAoUOYRFoCFivjx5gwBGTYtu2X5QH2LpXgJsijjQzzqpMYDzicATDumdYEDIUCIHAMrniGl4uhAtZurgQA).

### Update:

As requested by @jcalz, here is the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBtAUDGAb3wJgEsATALhgHIEQpaAaEggBwEMoALG2gPQs2MYDzIAbCnBRgaeUqWKLFlfp2Q9hK0l17rN2naPFSZcnCJ3Ljq6nQkgA5mTBHbHbnwfPX74wC%20rB5EVsZqdDIu0Chw-rZ63vQo0ahxwR5BYYo2IRHJEChQAAqcEBAA7iBwFPHGifwyhVAAtFzlVTV1ilkhuR75TbIUAMLgAGZkcAC23GTg3SoNkWjDLaBgkzNzCxm2vcYAunukBznZ5Pa07BKcAJ5OCIhgtSeKy9e3D08vi2KS0lk8guBH6tny42q0zGYCgCAkEGKX0eSF%20b3qXn4kJm63AcJACMWBDOKmOYRJZOJrEOMDKonA0AA3DABAJRJwwGBGPAUNMQAA3FAwXhkdBlQpwKDzMC09AQEDTIWMHixekUIWimDq9jDWSwcDkKC4XBQO46mAAJSQqAA8gAjABWKGAsCwNgi0DgricjJIy093t9BH%20ZlkAH4aDJOBRwBI7pbrSh7U6XdhDr6Ar7cAIAFQ5-A5mCIQroJ62x3OqDoKAgcibVUBsBOGASMhpTgSGCJCAFmAAAXVEGAXvYUoNPCgUHYECorOgnGAAGsBbFxo4KgA6UDTAScAQAdgArABOQ8AJgAHABGK8CM%20XgAsZ4fAAYCwITWahaVeBAADwACowCgAAeqAvKWKDRrG8ZWsgSYVqmhwAHyYKEBDYABiA3CgACSLygXWMCLigdwgOMMAAYcNAABQiCBtEAZh2ESHhBEgTSoHgRQ6CEJcNCuOMqq4RQwFgcMcpwoGXaYnWQlwDAP48GJ3GSV6TYwAEYRhpazrVBQf4icwileMhYQ0IQAQAJQwAAZGENFMVhOH4eqHEqRJ6EYvocmqkpHkQTAjY%20hcIaAhYgmqiMpjhQFPE8tBYBxgm8HJpWaZBioWm2DpYLGNgADSREkWRFFKf%200UAuYyHUTAAAGAAkhD%20VxnmNYQkUKcUFoBAIdUwDp3UwDQSm9U1ACiYFwAuUB-iCKjlX%20lWhmAyGFZSISkMF80EMhAR1Zl%20wXBZ1kkDZGCofyICUBm2BgIg0x2rEnHiYFNEMb5Cm4edl3XRQJC5TgRWuMRpHkTAuG1bh62aSQNBgCggpwFm4zPC60qiFGqCLUBrWBVGMZJbBiZpUhyE0WWaA0ABVkjV4-4Achvqo2A6MGsOUHY-TFOJjOCWE8lcHlimUBpsZXDmCUXhobQLAyb%20NAWnpNR-sFxnBahbrWV52IwDRrGwHxlDi7JMi3FKgpKcZYXmJpMDg5TEA2f0BvwCAjBK%20bZCW9LGBhGbcw%207wmAYFggi0DAAA%20kcyZL-mh2HQgXDp7US3qo1NQHFsoKNdXHfVTVp7Co0CJnKBe0HPD7Yd5AUTRlA2d22CUDSWAMFAnuBznXg12Qdc27INk0Rz3Dd7%20sq0mAdxWcPMXmMZ7ed9nVvyzwTuZdlPJQIgcAyt2GbGhs0Cr%20gWAj1zv48-B6%20HwysCU2M0zsOAeoADLu4u2GK8rBkleDpo6nBt2dWUkmyayICyNkABlHgSApAwCerpUAKs-4UQASgIB9NjJKxmgAORAOqZCxk7TIC1AsWAFQOSwBFOgG49wUTPFEjWOswAJCIHVAlF0G4SDt34DaZABsjAaB8rQAAgpoGAr97jWiMI4FwFhaDv3kUYKIoo0j8CVqkWIKjVhSw6PpfgPArw6MKC8GEWxZhjgUUYowdDvioiuEiehPxXgkGxNCPE8JETIhcfwAAYlCGE%20IEROPsYw4QmZjToJSqgU%20wovwO15lmaJQshRuhIJQCMQVQEhU8LwLJwVMrl15HqApOTMoDzAFk1JGVcBaVwEfWArgRbjVYoqWEaEr6xMVrzH6XlGl1hFigCgqS%20Y1NbjgdMbjqh61dpTe2FFHbOxEM0yswzRkbnYMWHgNE8rLEppsrw6JintKgJGRMj9n4I1hO-EAn92DYAOS3dElTznwS3HPWQA1BmVlaSU2EXSUAfKqoPYaRYCKTARhQE41kN48KKDvGUqyXTrKSXUrMR8CRArkfXMALS2l6kBU7KyvogA) that demonstrates full code.

Minimal reproducible example:

```
const routes = [
  {
    id: 'root', path: '/', children: [
      {
        id: 'auth', path: 'auth', children: [
          { id: 'login', path: 'login', },
          { id: 'register', path: 'register', },
          { id: 'resetPassword', path: 'reset-password', },
          { id: 'resendConfirmation', path: 'resend-confirmation', },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'playground',
        path: 'playground',
        children: [
          { id: 'formControlsPlayground', path: 'form-controls', },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
] as const;

// Please note that these Ids are typed manually for simplicity, actual program auto-generates them from the routes object.
type Id = "root" | "auth" | "login" | "register" | "resetPassword" | "resendConfirmation" |
  "playground" | "formControlsPlayground"


declare const routeComponentLookup: Record<Id, string>;

type Routes = typeof routes; // need to change this type to recursive one, so that injectElement function can be called recursively

const injectElement = (routes: Routes) => {
  const injectedRoutes: RouteObject[] = [];
  for (let route of routes) {
    injectedRoutes.push({
      path: route.path,
      element: routeComponentLookup[route.id],
      children: route.children ? injectElement(route.children) : undefined,
    });
  }
  return injectedRoutes;
};

console.log(injectElement(routes));
```

Comment: I don't get it, why don't you make `injectElements` accept `readonly RouteObject[]` instead of the unbelievably specific `Routes` type, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbvlbm)?  Does anything specifically prevent your from doing so?

Comment: @jcalz I cannot use that because it will refer `route.id` as `string`, but I need `string literal`. Please read my comment inside `injectElements` function.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to show (with code, not just comments) specifically what goes wrong if you make the change I suggest.  Otherwise I have nothing to test against, and since I'm skeptical of the claim that you need a string literal *type*, I want to wait until I see a clear demonstration of its usefulness before I spend a lot of effort of it.

Comment: @jcalz I have added full code (mostly from your yesterday's code) in the playground. Please check update part of the question.

Comment: So like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mA8xXN) maybe?  If so then I could write up an answer explaining, but you need to [edit] so the [mre] of your issue is in plaintext; maybe like [the code from here](https://tsplay.dev/wXvr9m) so it's not so long?  Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz The solution works perfectly fine, I have verified it in my project too. Also, added a minimal reproducible example code in question's update part. Please post the answer. I understood everything in the solution, but if you add explanation to the answer, then it will be beneficial to future visitors. Thanks for the easier and quicker solution!

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance; it is close to my bedtime now so I will come back sometime tomorrow morning (uh, well, morning in my time zone anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `routeComponentLookup` is of type

```
declare const routeComponentLookup: Record<Id, string>;
```

and you're looking up the `id` property of each element (recursively) of the `routes` parameter to `injectElement`, then you need that `id` property to be of type `Id`, and you can define your desired recursive type accordingly:

```
interface MyRoute {
  id?: Id;
  path?: string;
  element?: string;
  children?: readonly MyRoute[];
}
```

And then your `injectElement()` function should take a `readonly MyRoute[]` parameter, and its implementation only needs to change enough to account for the possibility of a missing `id`, like this:

```
const injectElement = (routes: readonly MyRoute[]) => {
  const injectedRoutes: MyRoute[] = [];
  for (let route of routes) {
    if (route.id === undefined) continue; // test for id here
    injectedRoutes.push({
      path: route.path,
      element: routeComponentLookup[route.id],
      children: route.children ? injectElement(route.children) : undefined,
    });
  }
  return injectedRoutes;
};

injectElement(routes); // okay
```

It's either that or `id` should be required, and your output needs to include it, as shown here:

```
interface MyRoute {
  id: Id; // required
  path?: string;
  element?: string;
  children?: readonly MyRoute[];
}

const injectElement = (routes: readonly MyRoute[]) => {
  const injectedRoutes: MyRoute[] = [];
  for (let route of routes) {
    injectedRoutes.push({
      path: route.path,
      element: routeComponentLookup[route.id],
      children: route.children ? injectElement(route.children) : undefined,
      id: route.id // add id here
    });
  }
  return injectedRoutes;
};
injectElement(routes); // okay
```

Either way should work, depending on your needs.  You might even want the output type of `injectElement()` to be different from its input type, but I won't bother showing that here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-P4Ai77H34igMzZSLGQWB7VAtTpscDSKAAGRAIAA1og2DRSQzvQAeXWsPlgawAPg1YA4nTQnGAJIAagBGIgkOyoOCtDgjmAAWS25OQJJZBEoYpguoF3J4O87nK8KDEKEHXyP335XluhjAO4lUrAMuXq-lKoFbnxBFG0HIMAlSgABRc9LyZGAAApCzQcUUElaVZRXNdUBVABKTBuyneR-1gOxgJQChULg98SJVfUvy8cFoPPAt5RgEBWngeUIEwzdVmYmD5QAOkoTAMCwdMUHaMAiMw0YQzARAUH3VYgIZVBiNYni2EQCBuCgjj5BOcVeJOa55DPC9yz09di1LMSvirWt62wWC+IoFFvHve4zNQHjXOkGARUA4CwJMr5uPXTyhQfTCaGE0SiMM1YLAcyhEXQuSf3kKQoEQOAwD8xSiJIiBvw1LcFMZAKIOC1A2JxGB+H4Ria22fEf37QcIGHMcACYcMA2d50XFCGI4uo9xquqpAAR0QDoiK8E5r3ZLs5OMiD5tvXCwvuJ8EJfN8BvXKjUV-PMAIIxSyvLfUKtI58kLIz9ZkwjBsI4vCcsZPLWJoPa0PRLADtIGioLolj10Y5jYLY7rlBKpT8tU9TNO00hdJBjyDKeZbTNRlALLLazqzrNh7N4yhnNMLyHgcimfLe0DwPLK7QoMe4IpgKK7Bip46gSvVaoxCg9X47gghQJKUq8dLMuy073uU9cCpIdVpxh86goh5LRvqxq3CAA)